# Select multiple rows based on increments of a column value

Tags: mysql, count, row

I have a table (action_tbl) as follows:

```
ActionID | Frame | Player_ID
----------------------------
1234     | 15    | 1
1235     | 15    | 1
1236     | 30    | 1
1237     | 280   | 1
1238     | 10    | 2
1239     | 60    | 2
1240     | 320   | 2
```

I'd like to write a script in MySQL to count number of actions for each player during a 240 frame period (for frame between 0-240, Frame_Period is 0, 241-480, 1, etc).
So the output should be as follow:

```
Count_Actions | Frame_Period | Player_ID
----------------------------
3             | 0            | 1
1             | 1            | 1
2             | 0            | 2
1             | 1            | 2
```

Edited

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It was a typo. I edited it.

Comment: can you create a separated table for frame period ranges?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The table (players action during a match) has more than 700k rows, and more than 500 Player_ID. Also, the max value for `frame` is different for each match.

Comment: Check my answer, I will try to remove the derivated table. Im thinking using a division `Frame % 240` to get frame_id

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The maximum value for the `frame` is changing per match `max(frame)` is near to 98000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a025/3)**

```
SELECT frame_id as Frame_Period, `Player_ID`, count(*) as Count_Actions
FROM action_tbl a
JOIN (SELECT 0 as frame_id, 0 low_limit, 240 high_limit
      UNION
      SELECT 1 as frame_id, 241 low_limit, 480 high_limit
      UNION
      SELECT 2 as frame_id, 481 low_limit, 720 high_limit
      UNION
      SELECT 3 as frame_id, 721 low_limit, 960 high_limit
     ) as frame_range
  ON a.`Frame` between frame_range.low_limit
                   and frame_range.high_limit
GROUP BY `Player_ID`, frame_id
ORDER BY `Player_ID`, frame_id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| frame_id | Player_ID | Count_Actions |
|----------|-----------|---------------|
|        0 |         1 |             3 |
|        1 |         1 |             1 |
|        0 |         2 |             2 |
|        1 |         2 |             1 |
```

**[Second aproach](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a025/7)**

```
SELECT truncate((Frame - 1) / 240, 0) as Frame_Period, 
       `Player_ID`, 
        count(*) as Count_Actions
FROM action_tbl
GROUP BY `Player_ID`, Frame_Period
ORDER BY `Player_ID`, Frame_Period
```

Comment: Check my edit. I test with border cases for Frame `239,240,241` and looks ok